# Beamer presentation - same image placement over successive slides

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, align, positioning

I'm doing my first presentation with latex beamer. My presentation does include some graphics, of which I want some to appear on several successive slides. However, I'm not able to place these images at the same position on each of those slides, since they cover different amounts of text and as a result the images are shifted.

What I tried:
Using the figure environment, aligning the image at the bottom and overwriting latex' default values with the following code

```
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgfb9e074}]{Zeilenmatrix}
\begin{itemize}
\item Jedes Lateinische Quadrat kann als \((3 \times n^2)\) -Matrix gesehen werden,
die \alert{Zeilenmatrix}
\item In jeder Spalte steht ein Zeilenindex \(i\), ein Spaltenindex \(j\), und das
Element in Position \((i,j)\)
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[b!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{Zeilenmatrix.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label={sec:org7ce40ce}]{Zeilenmatrix}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bedingung an Lateinisches Quadrat, bedeutet hier folgendes:
``\emph{In je zwei Zeilen der Zeilenmatrix treten alle \(n^2\) möglichen geordneten
Paare wirklich auf (und daher genau einmal)}''
\item Permutation der Symbole resultiert in Permutation der Zeilen, Spalten, oder Elemente
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[b!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{Zeilenmatrix.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

You sould load `package` `tikz` in the preample

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

and replace

```
\begin{figure}[b!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{Zeilenmatrix.png}
\end{figure}
```

by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=2cm] at (current page.south){%
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{Zeilenmatrix.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**NOTE 1:** there is no effect of floating positioners in `beamer`.

**NOTE 2:** if you make slides with only slightly different content, you should learn about `\only` et al.

**NOTE 3:** you compile your document twice.